# Espresso : how to click on image click button on phone camera

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing tests using espresso,my app intends to phone camera, where i press the click button manually,and then it migrates to  the next screen,I am not able to automate the image click button in test code,how can i access camera using code through which i can do the same.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot access camera UI using Espresso because it doesn't works across device apps.                     Instead you could use [Espresso-Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html) to simulate the behavior. And in case you want to access camera code you could use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) which works across device apps..

Comment: Thats correct, camera is different application in context to your app. You can use UIAutomator instead to simulate camera/images actions in the device.

Answer (score 1):

You should not open the camera intent or you'll have no way of getting any resulting image back from it (without pressing the camera button manually).

Have a look at the **Stubbing out the Camera** section of this website:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso#stubbing-out-the-camera

This way you test your activity by simulating an actual image "returned" to your app from the Camera.

**Update**

And this is the method I use to get a bitmap to test:

```
public static Bitmap getTestBitmap(Context context, String resourceName) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Bitmap ret = null;
    int imageResource = resources.getIdentifier(
            resourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"
            + resources.getResourcePackageName(imageResource) + '/'
            + resources.getResourceTypeName(imageResource) + '/'
            + resources.getResourceEntryName(imageResource));
    try {
        ret = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), pictureUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And then I save the bitmap in internal storage and get the uri:

```
public static Uri saveToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmapImage, String fileName) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/pictures
    File directory = cw.getDir("pictures", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    return Uri.fromFile(new File(mypath.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Comment: i am getting  5-27 15:20:24.183 3135-3553/com.android.local E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Mohit/IMG_20160527_152024.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-27 15:20:24.183 3135-3553/com.android.local E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Mohit/IMG_20160527_152024.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: The message says that the file does not exist in that device but maybe this is due to a problem with the app permissions. Anyway, I never use external images to test, I think it's better to use images from app resources. See my update with the method I use to get a bitmap to test.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but it's something I struggled with myself and I would like to post an answer to help someone else.  Here is how you click the camera button from a chooser (after you set it up), you use UIAutomator, as suggested by PunitD in the comments of the original post.  This will pick up from where the test is showing a chooser on the screen.

```
public static final int waitTimeNativeApi = 6000;

public static void await(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted while sleeping");
        }
    }

private void takePhoto() {

    boolean usePixels = true;

    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    UiObject titleTextUI = device.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .className("android.widget.TextView")
            .text("Camera")
    );

    try {
        titleTextUI.clickTopLeft();

        if (usePixels) {
            takePhotoForPixels(device);
        } else {
            takePhotoForSamsung(device);
        }

    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException unofe) {
        unofe.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void takePhotoForPixels(UiDevice device) {

    // close the app selector to go back to our app so we can carry on with Espresso

    await(waitTimeNativeApi);

    //TAP on the camera icon
    device.click(device.getDisplayWidth() / 2, device.getDisplayHeight() - 100);

    await(waitTimeNativeApi);

    //Get the OK button
    device.click(device.getDisplayWidth() / 2, device.getDisplayHeight() - 100);

    await(waitTimeNativeApi);

}

private void takePhotoForSamsung(UiDevice device) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

    // close the app selector to go back to our app so we can carry on with Espresso
    UiObject titleTextUI = device.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .className("android.widget.TextView")
            .text("Camera")
    );

    titleTextUI.clickTopLeft();

    await(waitTimeNativeApi);

    //TAP on the camera icon
    device.click(device.getDisplayWidth() / 2, device.getDisplayHeight() - 50);

    //Get the OK button
    UiObject cameraOkUi = device.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .className("android.widget.TextView")
            .text("OK")
    );

    cameraOkUi.click();

    await(waitTimeNativeApi);

}
```

In this way, you will take an actual photo and get the results back in onActivityResult.